# load div background images with javascript at runtime (through/with? CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, image

The app I am looking to alter is very simplistic HTMLwise--just a bunch of DIVs.  All the heavy formatting work is done in the style sheet.  The challenges I am having are with changing background images at run time.  Things like:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.setProperty('background-image', '1.png');
```

or

```
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = '1.png';
```

don't work because (I think) the HTML values will always be "overridden" by CSS values.  And (if I am correct) any object model you get from:

```
var ms = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(id), null);
```

is ready only...

I've seen other items on this site and elsewhere that don't seem to apply exactly:  changing a button image.  Using Angular.  Loading sprites.  CSSes not involved.  Image swapping carousels (that involved JQuery).

I won't bore you with the other hacky workwrounds I've considered/explored because I feel there must be a way to do this with javascript and CSS, right?

My question is how do you use javascript to change images in a style sheet or change html divs that are covered by a style sheet?

Comment: Maybe you have to wait to stylesheets to load and apply? Try placing your code inside `window.onload = function(){}`

Comment: "All the heavy formatting work is done in the style sheet." then just change the classname

Comment: I have confirmed the window has loaded.  Any way I really don't think I have valid syntax for editing background images that are governed by CSS.  The only way I know is inline HTML definitions and DOM set statements.  Both of which (again I think) get superceeded by the style sheet.

Comment: @Daniel_L and everybody.  The images need to be set by dynamically set/derived data so referring to another pre-defined class won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing its `style.backgroundImage` is possible:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrJEZO

Click on the "Click to Change" to see this in effect.
(The image links are the first few Google results of `Sample Image`)

If your code doesn't work, I guess @liveFor10 is correct in the comments - maybe the race condition of calling the `change()` function is run before the css is loaded.

Comment: The line up above:

  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = '1.png';

when I can break shows .backgroundImage = "" both before and after the line is executed.  Maybe because it is not coming from document.defaultView.getComputedStyle...

Comment: @liveFor10 Would it help by adding `console.trace()` after the line to see how it is triggered? Now we know that the problem is not with JS not functioning, I guess we are close ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules to a css document by appending text nodes or modifying the inner html.

```
var rule = document.createTextNode('.myimg { background: url(1.png) }');
[...document.querySelector('style')].pop().appendChild(rule);
```

Now you can reference the added rule.

```
var el = document.getElementById('blah');
el.className += ' myimg'; // references a dynamically created css rule
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel_L.  This still doesn't let me dynamically assign new values for images in the css.  Like for action or for hover.  I guess I confused the thread by showing what's not working and then asking for direction to something completely different.  I mean even a perfectly functioning DOM assignment doesn't affect the css.

Comment: you can simply create a `style` tag and append a text node with your css string

Comment: edited your question title and answer...basically you can create css rules and append them to style tags or even parse the css rules on a page if you wanted

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I don't want to stop you/them.  You can keep them coming.  Right now I am looking at another stackoverflow thread 1033156 that says you can't define pseudo classes like action and hover in inline html.  Of course click and mouseup/out I considered.  One work around is to always have your DIVs inside an anchor.  You can change the background image of the anchor and have the DIV inherit it upon hover...checking to see if that would work here